# R equivalent of Stata's Absorb

Tags: r, panel-data, usage-statistics

I would like to control for a factor variable that contains over a hundred levels without outputting the results of that control to a summary table.  Note, I am also interested in replicating the speed of Stata's command, rather than merely cosmetic changes to output.

In Stata I can use "absorb" like so:

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r14/abdata.dta, clear
. xtreg n w k i.year, fe

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs     =      1,031
Group variable: id                              Number of groups  =        140

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.6277                                         min =          7
     between = 0.8473                                         avg =        7.4
     overall = 0.8346                                         max =          9

                                                F(10,881)         =     148.56
corr(u_i, Xb)  = 0.5666                         Prob > F          =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           n |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           w |  -.2731482   .0551503    -4.95   0.000    -.3813896   -.1649068
           k |   .5648036   .0212211    26.62   0.000     .5231537    .6064535
             |
        year |
       1977  |  -.0347963   .0188134    -1.85   0.065    -.0717206    .0021281
       1978  |  -.0583286   .0190916    -3.06   0.002    -.0957989   -.0208583
       1979  |   -.070047   .0190414    -3.68   0.000    -.1074187   -.0326752
       1980  |  -.0889378   .0189788    -4.69   0.000    -.1261867   -.0516889
       1981  |  -.1401502   .0186309    -7.52   0.000    -.1767163   -.1035841
       1982  |  -.1603768   .0188132    -8.52   0.000    -.1973008   -.1234528
       1983  |  -.1621103   .0222902    -7.27   0.000    -.2058585   -.1183621
       1984  |  -.1258136   .0282391    -4.46   0.000    -.1812373   -.0703899
             |
       _cons |   2.255419   .1772614    12.72   0.000     1.907515    2.603323
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  .64723143
     sigma_e |  .12836859
         rho |  .96215208   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F test that all u_i=0: F(139, 881) = 126.32                  Prob > F = 0.0000
```

Using absorb removes the fixed effects

```
. reghdfe n w k, absorb(id year)
(converged in 7 iterations)

HDFE Linear regression                            Number of obs   =      1,031
Absorbing 2 HDFE groups                           F(   2,    881) =     362.67
                                                  Prob > F        =     0.0000
                                                  R-squared       =     0.9922
                                                  Adj R-squared   =     0.9908
                                                  Within R-sq.    =     0.4516
                                                  Root MSE        =     0.1284

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           n |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           w |  -.2731482   .0551503    -4.95   0.000    -.3813896   -.1649068
           k |   .5648036   .0212211    26.62   0.000     .5231537    .6064535
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    Absorbed |       F(147, 881) =    120.660   0.000             (Joint test)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Absorbed degrees of freedom:
---------------------------------------------------------------+
 Absorbed FE |  Num. Coefs.  =   Categories  -   Redundant     |
-------------+-------------------------------------------------|
          id |          140             140              0     |
        year |            8               9              1     |
---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best alternative I could find is the lfe package, which implements models with high dimensional fixed effects or/and instrumental variables.

You can specify fixed effects after a vertical bar like so:

```
felm(n ~ w _ k | year, df)
```

The year coefficients will be absorbed in the final specification.  The problem with this method is that it does now allow you to predict observations.

Edit: Update

The R library `estimatr` has the function `lm_robust`, which has a fixed_effects parameter that absorbs FE and works better than any library I've found online.  Highly recommend.

Comment: Thanks, the `felm` command works fine. However, when I use `huxreg` to table my regression results, the intercept as well as AIC and logLik are omitted... Also quite a drawback from the perspective of a smooth workflow.

Comment: Yup.  I'm really disappointed by the lack of libraries in R that can generate clustered standard error, fixed effect models while preserving the ability to predict, generate interaction plots, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a built-in way to do this but `broom::tidy` plus a little bit of filtering based on the factor name will do what you want:

Sample data:

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(y=rnorm(1000),
                 f=factor(sample(1:50,size=1000,replace=TRUE)),
                 x=rnorm(1000))

m <- lm(y~f+x,data=dd)
```

One way (depends on `grepl()`, which is base R [with which I'm more familiar], which is mixing and matching paradigms a little bit)

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
tidy(m) %>%
    filter(!grepl("^f[0-9]+",term))
##          term    estimate  std.error statistic   p.value
## 1 (Intercept) -0.22643955 0.18852186 -1.201131 0.2299999
## 2           x -0.03330846 0.03101449 -1.073964 0.2831116
```

Or you can do it with `stringr::str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
tidy(m) %>%
    filter(!str_detect(term,"^f[0-9]+"))
```

The particular regular expression I used is based on the name of the factor plus the names of the levels.  In your case it would be `"^year[0-9]+"`, or just `"^year"` if you were feeling lucky

Comment: This is an elegant solution for display purposes, but it's computationally much slower than whatever Stata is doing in the backend with absorb.  With absorb in stata, I can run the regression instantly, whereas in R it takes nearly 5 minutes.

Comment: I think that probably has to do more with the way Stata is *running the regression* rather than with how results are reported.  Thus it might be  a separate question. I see that `xtreg` is a panel method (about which I know barely anything): have you looked at the `plm` package (which BTW does also have a `tidy()` method written for it) ...??

Comment: Thank you -- will take a look at this!  I seen now my question was misleading, and I apologize.  The fact that Stata suppresses output of variables with lots of levels is an added bonus to what is really important to me, which is quickly controlling for those variables in large datasets.

Comment: OK.  Someone who knows their way around panel regression would probably be able to translate from Stata to `plm::plm()` syntax much faster than I would ... probably? `index="year",  model="within"` (not sure what the `effect` parameter does ...)

Answer (score 1):

You did two completely different regressions.
xtreg is for panel data (x for id, t for time). Regardless of balanced or unbalanced panel, a second dimension orthogonal to id (usually takes the form of time) is necessary for panel data. In R, you can use the `plm` package which provides pooled OLS, first difference, between, within/fixed effects, random effects, nested, etc. estimators for panel data.

However, if your data do not have a panel structure (i.e. a unique id-time identifier for each observation), then you cannot apply the within transformation in `plm` or `xtreg`. That would be the case for, e.g. repeated cross-section data, or clustered/hierarchical cross-section data. `reghdfe` uses a different algorithm for high dimensional fixed effects. Multiple R packages aim for the same purpose, including `lfe` (felm function), `fixest` (feols function), `biglm` (biglm function), `estimatr` (lm_robust function), etc. From my personal experience, `estimatr` is generally faster than others.