# cannot allocate memory in static R regression

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, stata, panel-data

I'm trying to run a regression in R and I want to control the fipsmerg variable by factors but R gives me a memory error.

input:

```
myprobit <-  glm(a_imt~a_imt_1+totpop+reltrad_1+reltrad_2+reltrad_3+reltrad_4+as.factor(fipsmerg),data = data, family=binomial(link="probit"))
lmr <- lm(a_imt~a_imt_1+totpop+reltrad_1+reltrad_2+reltrad_3+reltrad_4+as.factor(fipsmerg),data = data)
```

output:

```
cannot allocate vector of size 16.7 Gb
```

(my database has around 900 thousand observations)
One person suggested I use something in R that is equivalent to Stata's absorb, but I don't know what it would be. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49802084/190277 ?

Comment: How many unique “fipsmerg” values are there in the dataset?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3170401/190277 is promising, although that describes only linear models, not GLMs.